# Program Will Not Loop Back to Other Choices

Tags: python

I am trying to get my program to allow me to access the time, date, and open chrome choices an infinite amount of times in any order however it only seems to go in order of 1,2,3 then it ends and will not allow me to bring the time or the date up again if i choose for example "Open Chrome"

I have tried while statements, if statements, for statements, but nothing seems to work.

```
import datetime
import OpenChromeFunction
# open a public URL, in this case, Google.ca
url = "https://www.google.ca"


print("Hello, World!", "\n", "--------------------------------------------------")

name = input("What is your name?:")

greetings = 'Hello!'
print(greetings, name, "\n", "--------------------------------------------------")

now = datetime.datetime.now()
choice = input("What do you want to do?:")

if choice == "Time":
    print('Current Time is:', now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    choice = input("What do you want to do?:")

if choice == "Date":
    print('Current Date is:', now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    choice = input("What do you want to do?:")

if choice == "Open Chrome":
    OpenChromeFunction.openchrome()
    choice = input("What do you want to do?:")
```

I expected it to allow me to get the time or date information again after opening google chrome from the file. but I only get Process finished with exit code 0

Here is the code with me trying a while loop, i think.

```
import datetime
import OpenChromeFunction
# open a public URL, in this case, Google.ca
url = "https://www.google.ca"
now = datetime.datetime.now()

print("Hello, World!", "\n", "--------------------------------------------------")

name = input("What is your name?:")

greetings = 'Hello!'
print(greetings, name, "\n", "--------------------------------------------------")
choice = input("What do you want to do?:")

while choice == "Date and Time":
    print('Current Time is:', now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), "\n", "Current Date 
is:", now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    choice = input("What do you want to do?:")

while choice == "Open Chrome":
    OpenChromeFunction.openchrome()
    choice = input("What do you want to do?:")
```

Comment: Second and third if should be elif, also surround ifs by a while

Comment: A while loop is what you need. Can you post the code you tried using a while loop?

Comment: unspecified != infinite (go ahead, downvote for pedantry)

Comment: I used while loops and everything seemed to break itself, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @MatthewLodge `while` loops are fundamental/basic element of coding. If you refuse to try a `while` loop again just because the first time you tried using it, things stopped working, then you're going to be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what you want:

```
import datetime    
import OpenChromeFunction

# open a public URL, in this case, Google.ca
url = "https://www.google.ca"
now = datetime.datetime.now()

print("Hello, World!", "\n", 40*"-")

name = input("What is your name?:")

greetings = 'Hello!'
print(greetings, name, "\n", 40*"-")

Open_Chrome = "Open Chrome"
Date_and_Time = "Date and Time"

while True:
    choice = input("What do you want to do?:")

    if choice == Date_and_Time:
        print(
            'Current Time is:', now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
             "\n", "Current Date is:", now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        )
        continue
        # `continue` goes to the top of the loop and restarts
        # `continue` skips the portion of the loop located below/after
        # the `continue` keyword.

    if choice == Open_Chrome:
        OpenChromeFunction.openchrome()
        continue
        # `continue` goes to the top of the loop and restarts
        # `continue` skips the portion of the loop located below/after
        # the `continue` keyword.

    print(
        repr(choice) + "is invalid.",
        "Maybe try:",
        Open_Chrome,
        Date_and_Time,
        sep = "\n"
    )
```

Comment: I'll try this thanks! Still learning python so each new bit of info I can get is much appreciated